# Will Golang properly optimize a for range loop and avoid copying each object?

Tags: arrays, go, copy, slice

In some Go code I'm working on, I often see loops like so:

```
var slice []SomeType
...fill slice...
for idx, obj := range slice {
    obj.SetSomeValue(123)
    slice[idx] = obj
}
```

`obj` is going to be a copy of the object found in `slice` (although not pointers, since it uses a shallow copy).

What I'm wondering is: Is the existing Go compiler capable of optimizing the loop by applying the `SetSomeValue()` directly to the object at `slice[idx]` or will it make two copies as the code above implies?

My simple solution would be to make use of a pointer instead, so the slice becomes:

```
var slice []*SomeType
```

then the loop `obj` variable is a pointer to the object and thus it only copies one pointer here and the `SetSomeValue()` call directly applies to the object in `slice`.

Another solution is to make the call on the slice like so:

```
for idx, _ := range slice {
    slice[idx].SetSomeValue(123)
}
```

However, in this case, the `slice[idx].` gets repeated and when compiled could also end up repeated many times (although I still think this is better than the first approach).

Comment: If you are worried about the copy, use the indexed access. Compiler can optimize repeated use of index. Optimizing access to a copy with direct access to slice would change language semantics and introduce bugs, so the compiler should not do that anyway. You can also use indexed access once by assigning the address of the slice index to a pointer var.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Right, the first statement inside the for block could be `obj := &slice[idx]`. I'm worried because some of those lists have millions of items (about 10M). I think it's a useful optimization, especially since the object (SomeType) is not that small.

Comment: Use indexed access then. You don't want to copy the whole thing. Don't expect the compiler to optimize copies though, it would change the meaning of this: `for a,  b:=range slice { slice[a].x=1; y:=b.x }` With copy-optimization you suggested, `y` is always 1.